# FAB button in wrong position

Tags: android, user-interface, layout, material-design, floating-action-button

I've been struggling with the position of my FAB and at this point, for an unknown reason (for me), the button is located on top-left, when it's suposed to go bottom-rigth.

This is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/l_gray"
android:weightSum="1">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_vehiculos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:divider="@color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="15dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.83"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_white_plus"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/s_gray"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/view" />
```

And this is the result.

[image: FAB missplaced]

Answer (score 0):

Relative layout and its children cannot use the layout weight and weightsum attributes and its behavior.  Also direct children of relative layout dont have the layout gravity attribute either so any kind of behavior your are expecting from these attributes wont work

So in order to get the fab to bottom right you need to use the positioning attributes usable inside a relative layout so if you were to enable the `android:layout_alignParentBottom` attribute for the FAB by setting its value to `true` then the button would move to the bottom and then if you also enable the `android:layout_alignParentRight` attribute for the FAB by setting it to `true` then the button would stick to the right end of the parent relative layout thus you successfully positioned your button to the bottom right of your relativelayout(parent).

But in your case a much simpler solution would be to just change the root relativelayout to linearlayout as from what I  can in your xml it is quite clear that the children of your root layout were setup for a linearlayout parent and you naively copy pasted that code into a layout with a root relative layout

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `RelativeLayout` for parent then you should use the following to send it to bottom right of view:

`android:alignParentRight="true"`

`android:alignParentEnd="true"`

`android:alignParentBottom="true"`

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues on your layout.

- `android:layout_weight` doesn't work with a `RelativeLayout`.
  You can check the [official doc here.](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight)
- `android:layout_gravity` doesn't work with a `RelativeLayout`.
  You can check the [official doc here.](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity)

You can achieve your layout in many ways:

- **Better:** Use a [`CoordinatorLayout`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) and `android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"`. And may be use a `RecyclerView` instead of a `ListView`.
- Use a `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`
- Use a `RelativeLayout` with `android:alignParentEnd="true"` and `android:alignParentBottom="true"`
- If you want to use a weight you can use the new [`PercentRelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html)